# ¿Consultar cantidad de registros duplicados en SQllite?

Tags: java, android-studio, base-de-datos, sql, sqlite

Estoy tratando de saber la cantidad de datos que tienen un mismo registro dentro de una base de datos en Sqlite. Por ejemplo para el registro **4545**, necesito saber que otros datos tienen ese mismo registro y regresar esa cantidad total.

Este es el código que tengo actualmente pero no me está retornando ningún valor.

```
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(" + CANTIDAD + ") FROM '" + myTable + "' where " + Utilidades.CAMPO_ID + " = '" + Codigo + "' COLLATE NOCASE", null);
```

Comment: Solucionado con **Long cant = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + myTable + " where id = " + Codigo, null);**

Answer (score 1):

La forma más común de hacerlo en SQL, es a través de un group by:

```
select
    campo1,
    campo2
    --, ... campos adicionales
from
    mi_esquema.mi_tabla
group by
    campo1,
    campo2
    --, ... campos adicionales
having
    count(*) > 1
```

Y con eso vas a saber qué registros tienes duplicados. Después tu tendrás que decidir qué estrategia usas para eliminarlos